# Pairwise paired t test, arguments don't not have the same length

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, paired-data

I have a data frame structured liked this:

```r
    $id subject:1,2,3,4...
    $condition: condition1, condition2, condition3, condition4...
    $day of experiment: day1, day2, day3, day4...
    $score:....
```

The packages I used were: `tidyverse, rstatix, ggpubr`

I ran a two way ANOVA repeated measures within days (as subjects are the same for the 4 days, and between the conditions

```r
    two.way.anova <- anova_test(data, wid=id, dv=score, within= day, between= condition)
```

there was a significant interaction and and thus I ran a one way ANOVA grouped for day to see the interaction between condition and score:

```r
    one.way.anova <- data |>   
    group_by(day) |> 
    anova_test(score~condition) |> 
    get_anova_table() |> 
    adjust_pvalue(method="bonferroni")
```

and so I tried to run a pairwise t test paired with this code:

```r
    pwc.one.way. <- data |> 
    group_by(day) |> 
    pairwise_t_test(score~con, paired = TRUE, 
       p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
```

and I get this error:

```r
    Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `data`.
    i `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
    x not all arguments have the same length
```

I have seen that others had the same problem and they say that data must have the same number on al days of experiment and indeed my data have the same number of subjects on all 4 days when you group them by day?

Can anyone see my stuff and maybe understand what is going on?

EDIT: as some people mentioned I should display my data also:

```
    data  <- structure(list(
id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", 
"64", "65", "66", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", 
"43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", 
"54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", 
"65", "66", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
"33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
"44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", 
"55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", 
"66", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", 
"34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", 
"45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", 
"56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66"
), 
condition = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
 score = c(17, 23, 48, 16, 9, 35, 8, 
46, 59, 14, 22, 57, 13, 18, 33, 21, 8, 38, 23, 10, 43, 48, 47, 
48, 31, 31, 11, 15, 52, 22, 38, 19, 26, 30, 39, 5, 33, 59, 25, 
40, 38, 6, 38, 17, 51, 32, 17, 52, 27, 30, 42, 1, 15, 10, 48, 
60, 34, 26, 53, 24, 33, 28, 37, 50, 26, 60, 24, 41, 5, 3, 28, 
45, 7, 35, 8, 28, 29, 43, 35, 9, 4, 32, 33, 27, 17, 32, 16, 9, 
48, 4, 9, 6, 49, 40, 54, 41, 20, 43, 55, 51, 41, 24, 49, 39, 
20, 44, 27, 3, 50, 46, 16, 37, 48, 7, 18, 3, 29, 32, 46, 11, 
38, 30, 49, 48, 55, 10, 8, 6, 16, 58, 31, 17, 29, 56, 2, 54, 
23, 54, 27, 58, 42, 53, 21, 20, 11, 40, 50, 39, 2, 4, 37, 55, 
46, 32, 57, 55, 14, 21, 15, 38, 7, 57, 60, 15, 57, 54, 57, 58, 
4, 14, 1, 44, 30, 55, 16, 39, 3, 16, 11, 40, 6, 51, 21, 51, 48, 
40, 6, 13, 28, 50, 43, 7, 49, 2, 27, 44, 35, 17, 37, 5, 41, 16, 
26, 51, 25, 38, 20, 55, 23, 14, 19, 26, 54, 4, 41, 8, 6, 58, 
56, 43, 4, 20, 43, 22, 1, 25, 9, 18, 2, 33, 1, 2, 45, 52, 29, 
22, 7, 16, 47, 11, 36, 39, 55, 53, 17, 48, 13, 30, 28, 7, 25, 
8, 3, 35, 5, 24, 37, 25, 21, 50, 11, 33, 45, 19)), row.names = c(NA, 
-264L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`paired=TRUE` is asking for the tests to be paired t-tests, so the data are composed of pairs of one observation in, say, condition A and one in condition B. This means that, for each day, the number of observations in the four conditions must be the same.

But

```
> with(data,table(day,condition))
   condition
day  A  B  C  D
  1 17 16 19 14
  2 17 16 19 14
  3 17 16 19 14
  4 17 16 19 14
```

so paired t-tests don't make any sense.

Maybe you mean `paired=FALSE`?

(Also, your code has a variable name `con` but your data has `condition`)

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to use a more common function to fit the model you want, perhaps *lmer()* or *nlme()*, and then use the *emmeans* package to make post-hoc comparisons.

Assuming I understand your code correctly, the applied-statistics part of this advice is to use estimated marginal means based on the fitted model rather than use *t*-tests on the raw data.